# clEnqueueCopyImageToBuffer 2d image to 1d array

Tags: image, memory, kernel, buffer, opencl

I'm trying to determine the "error" between two images (currently just a sum squared difference.)  I compute this in my first kernel and return a single image (black=perfect match, white=perfect error). I now want to reduce that image to a single "error" value in a second kernel.  My first game plan was to pass the "error" image to a second kernel for the reduction, but I found out that I can not read/write to an image within the same kernel... so I wanted to copy the image to a buffer, and I figured a reduction kernel on a 1d array buffer would be easier than a 2d array.  I could simply return the pixel values from the first kernel into a 1d array, but I wouldn't be able to debug as easy (by taking a look at the returned, "error" image.)

I can not find a definite answer, and my code appears to compile and run (haven't finished, just a few build up steps), however I am just trying to get a definite that clEnqueueCopyImageToBuffer can be used for a 2d image to a 1d buffer copy before I go any further.

PseudoCode:

```
// Create (or load) an OpenCV mat
Mat IMAGE (y, x, CV_32FC1, Scalar(0.0));
// Create the CL Image
image = clCreateImage2D(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEMCOPY_HOST_PTR, 
        & format, IMAGE.cols, IMAGE.rows,0,(void*)IMAGE.data, &err);
// Create a buffer to copy the image to after I do some work in a kernel
size_t image_size = {IMAGE.cols * IMAGE.rows * 1};
// Probably not the most correct way to create the buffer, but it works:     
image_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE |     
        CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, image_size,(void*)IMAGE.data, &err);
...
// Run first kernel on image then
clEnqueueCopyImageToBuffer(ocl_queue, image, image_mem,
         origin, region, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);
// Run second kernel on the buffer
```

It seems logical to me, however I have made logical assumptions before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly copy a 2D image to a 1D buffer (all OpenCL buffers are 1D anyway).

If your OpenCV image type is `CV_32FC1`, then your `image_size` definition would need to be `IMAGE.cols * IMAGE.rows * sizeof(float)`.

However, rather than incurring an additional copy, why not just perform the reduction over your 2D image and then just write the final result to a buffer? The logic for a 2D reduction isn't that much more difficult than a 1D reduction, and this doesn't require that you read/write from/to the same image.

Comment: Thanks... I'm trying to figure out the most efficient reduction (still learning).  My thought was to make a call to a single kernel multiple times and save off the values back to the original buffer (image or otherwise) so the next call to the kernel would still have access to the same buffer to best make use of being parallel, otherwise if I do it all in one kernel call as the reduction progresses a lot of threads cease to do any work... Thanks again!

Comment: All of those additional global memory loads/stores will cost you a lot of performance. On most GPUs, you're much better off doing the reduction in a single kernel, storing intermediate results to local memory.

Comment: I would like to take advantage of the float4 efficiency and didn't think I could use an image in the kernel with that type (ala: **https://github.com/jeremyong/opencl_in_action/tree/master/Ch10/reduction_complete**.) unless I convert the image to local memory first in additional to the intermediate results (doesn't sound as efficient to me)... I'll try it out and see where I can get. Thanks!